# Laravel 5.5 : cannot read a variable from .env file

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 5.5 when I do a simple :

```
$env = env('APP_ENV');
Log::info('environnement : ' . $env);
```

The log is always :

```
[2018-08-23 11:55:34] local.INFO: environnement :
```

And my .env file is :

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:+WXI)---hidden-----IXBfB2jTYAqo=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost:3000/
```

I am waiting for a response : "local". And don't understand why I receive null.

Comment: Is there your full .env file, maybe it has a problem with space " " character in .env file.

Comment: Thanks Sang for your answer. I already double cheked this .env file. No space or blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to clear cache?

```
php artisan config:clear
```

If you run your web using command `php artisan serve`, please close then run again.

Comment: YEEESSSS . It works now after a clear config and restart of my server. Merci Sang Nguyen.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `getenv()` function, not `env()` one.

Comment: thanks for this quick answer. I just tried getenv() instead of env() , without success. Returns null

Comment: Actually, `env()` is [Laravel's helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-env) for such purpose.

Comment: The more one knows... thanks, I always thought it's getenv for some reason